# How to get id of autosuggestion value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an auto suggestion script in which whenever I entered first alphabet I got all data from database. But how can i get different id of autosuggestion name every time? Because I have got one id for all "name" every time. I have get data from this page:this page is an AJAX script.

```
$qry = "select * from wp_case";
$my_q = mysql_query($qry);
if($my_q)
{ 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($my_q))
    {
        echo $row['CaseName'];
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input size="30" id="TextSearch" class="inputtext" name="TextSearch"
  value="" type="text"
  onclick="gett();" onchange="get();"
/>
```

my Table is:
   

        `Id: CaseName: LawyerId 

        204  abc        55      

        205  xyz       1       

        206  def       15`

`function gett()`

```
{
 $('#TextSearch').autocomplete('acomp.php');
}
```

Comment: Please show us your db table-structure

Answer (score 0):

Your Id will be contained within...

```
$row['Id']
```

We'd need to see your Javascript for your auto-suggestion (gett?) before we know what's going on though..

Comment: hello, i have also added my javascript too.

Comment: @prakash Yeah but that's just jQuery's auto complete, I don't think it supports anything to do with IDs.

Comment: so if u have any ideas, please enlighten so, i can try that stuff

Comment: By rights you should be converting the textual data server-side to an ID, and not relying on the POSTed value.